# Alternative to Tiled to do free shapes

Tags: libgdx, shapes, tiled

I am searching a tool like Tiled but allowing to make free shapes (not only rectangles or circles). Shapes with curves and such. Could you help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

Though, if you're looking for a tool very much like Tiled but with support for curves, be sure to add a comment to the [spline objects feature request](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/issues/562) and consider helping to [finish this pull request](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/pull/776).